# Direct and reported/indirect Speech

Tags: reported-speech, direct-speech

Direct Speech:

She said to me, "I **was thinking** of helping him but **changed**  my mind later on"

What is the correct indirect form??

a) She told me that she **had been thinking** of helping him but **changed** her mind.

b)She told me that she **had been thinking** of helping him but **had changed** her mind.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.  As you are practising back-shifting, you are probably expected to backshift both verb phrases to the past perfect.

There is an error near the end of both your examples... can you find it?

Comment: By the way, Can we write reported soeech without backshifting at all? For example: She told me She told me that she was thinking of helping him changed her  mind.

Comment: Got it. I need to say "her" mind